# Can I print in Haskell the type of a polymorphic function as it would become if I passed to it an entity of a concrete type?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-systems, polymorphic-functions

Here's a function polymorphic in 3 types:

```hs
:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

and here a non polymorphic function:

```hs
:t Data.Char.digitToInt
Data.Char.digitToInt :: Char -> Int
```

If we apply the former to the latter, we get a function polymorphic in 1 type:

```hs
:t (.) Data.Char.digitToInt
(.) Data.Char.digitToInt :: (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```

which means that `(.)` was "instantiated" (I'm not sure this is the correct term; as a C++ programmer, I'd call it so) with `b === Char` and `c === Int`, so the signature of the `(.)` that gets applied to `digitToInt` is the following

```hs
(Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```

My question is: is there a way to have this signature printed on screen, given `(.)`, `digitToInt` and the "information" that I want to apply the former to the latter?

For who's interested, this question was earlier closed as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368507/unifying-c-a-b-and-a-b-c).

Comment: in what language? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335704/haskell-how-to-infer-the-type-of-an-expression-manually/14558244#14558244) of mine contains a Prolog snippet that does that.

Comment: @WillNess, I was thinking about doing it from within `ghci`.

Comment: what's wrong with `> :t (.) Data.Char.digitToInt`?

Comment: @WillNess, that is not telling me what the type of the first argument to `(.)` is. Yes, I know, it's the type of the argument I'm giving to it, but that's the point of my question.

Comment: Check out my answer at the linked duplicate. For your exact question, the instantiation of the principle described there would be `:t undefined :: ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c) ~ ((Char -> Int) -> d) => ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)`, which replies `... :: (Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int`.

Comment: @Enlico Hm. Maybe? I'm not sure what "part of signature" and "rest of signature" mean to you. For function application specifically, the pattern is `:t undefined :: (type of function) ~ (type of argument -> fresh variable) => (comma separated unknowns)` (where the unknown could be, say, another copy of the function's type signature). If both the function and the argument are polymorphic, you should make sure to rename the variables in one or the other so there are no accidental equalities.

Comment: When working with concrete terms, it might be easier to define a helper `inContext :: a -> (a -> b) -> a` defined by `inContext = const`.  Then, at the GHCi prompt, the expression `inContext (.) $ \(.) -> (.) digitToInt` gives the inferred type directly, so you don't have to copy type signatures and make up fresh variables.  Note that `inContext` can be used infix, but I always mess up writing code with backticks in comments.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr  code snippets in comments can be enclosed in double backticks,  \`\`...\`\`, so the backticks inside the code are handled properly: ``> :t (.) `inContext` \(.) -> (.) Data.Char.digitToInt``.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr your answer is excellent and should really be added as such *somewhere*, if not here. I'm voting to reopen just in case you want to post it here rather than at [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65258061/revisions), since it's not an _exact_ duplicate anyway.

Comment: Here’s a neat hack: you can ask for the type of an expression with the subexpression you care about annotated with a scoped type variable. This type variable will fail to unify with any concrete type, and in order to check that, the typechecker must instantiate the inferred type, and will thus report that instantiated type: `:t let x :: forall t. _; x = ((.) :: t) digitToInt in x` says it can’t match `t` with `(Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int`. You can save this in your `.ghci` file as a custom command like `:def itype \ expr -> …`, but I think it’d be better to make a feature request.

Comment: @DanielWagner I've voted to reopen since there are more answers being shown in the comments here which probably ought to be posted as such, and I'm not sure where their authors would prefer to post them.

Comment: Okay, sure. Though it's a bit of a shame that this question page no longer has a way for future readers to discover the link to the other question (e.g. it doesn't appear in the "Linked" list on the right), which I think you can agree is very closely related even if you don't think its answers apply here.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I have inscluded the link in the question now.

Comment: @JonPurdy, I have to `:set` some extension for that, right? Would you explain that in an answer? I guess it could be useful for other readers.

Comment: @DanielWagner the answers there do apply, but not directly, they must be tweaked a bit... as for the link being gone, there is a way to see the revisions even when there are none yet, by  entering the URL manually (which I've included in my comment to you). you'd still see the link to the dup there even before the last edit on the question. :) (and now of course it has the clickable revisions link under it, titled "edited <time ago>", which contains the link to the dup).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other answers require the help of functions that have been defined with artificially restricted types, such as the `asTypeOf` function in the  answer from HTNW.  This is not necessary, as the following interaction shows:

```
Prelude> let asAppliedTo f x = const f (f x)

Prelude> :t head `asAppliedTo` "x"
head `asAppliedTo` "x" :: [Char] -> Char

Prelude> :t (.) `asAppliedTo` Data.Char.digitToInt
(.) `asAppliedTo` Data.Char.digitToInt
  :: (Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```

This exploits the *lack* of polymorphism in the lambda-binding that is implicit in the definition of `asAppliedTo`.  Both occurrences of `f` in its body must be given the same type, and that is the type of its result.  The function `const` used here also has its natural type `a -> b -> a`:

```
const x y = x
```

Answer (score 12):

There's this neat little function hidden in a corner of the `Prelude`:

```
Prelude.asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
asTypeOf x _ = x
```

It's documented as "forcing its first argument to have the same type as the second." We can use this to force the type of `(.)`'s first argument:

```
-- (.) = \x -> (.) x = \x -> (.) $ x `asTypeOf` Data.Char.digitToInt
-- eta expansion followed by definition of asTypeOf
-- the RHS is just (.), but restricted to arguments with the same type as digitToInt
-- "what is the type of (.) when the first argument is (of the same type as) digitToInt?"
ghci> :t \x -> (.) $ x `asTypeOf` Data.Char.digitToInt
\x -> (.) $ x `asTypeOf` Data.Char.digitToInt
  :: (Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```

Of course, this works for as many arguments as you need.

```
ghci> :t \x y -> (x `asTypeOf` Data.Char.digitToInt) . (y `asTypeOf` head)
\x y -> (x `asTypeOf` Data.Char.digitToInt) . (y `asTypeOf` head)
  :: (Char -> Int) -> ([Char] -> Char) -> [Char] -> Int
```

You can consider this a variation of @K.A.Buhr's idea in the comments—using a function with a signature more restrictive than its implementation to guide type inference—except we don't have to define anything ourselves, at the cost of not being able to just copy the expression in question under a lambda.

Comment: Indeed, my discovery of `asTypeOf` many years ago inspired my solution.

Answer (score 8):

I think @HTNW's answer probably covers it, but for completeness, here's how the `inContext` solution works in detail.

The type signature of the function:

```
inContext :: a -> (a -> b) -> a
```

means that, if you have a thing you want to type, and a "context" in which it's used (expressible as a lambda that takes it as an argument), say with types:

```
thing :: a1
context :: a2 -> b
```

You can force unification of `a1` (the general type of `thing`) with `a2` (the constraints of the context) simply by constructing the expression:

```
thing `inContext` context
```

Normally, the unified type `thing :: a` would be lost, but the type signature of `inContext` implies that the type of this whole resulting expression will also be unified with the desired type `a`, and GHCi will happily tell you the type of that expression.

So the expression:

```
(.) `inContext` \hole -> hole digitToInt
```

ends up getting assigned the type that `(.)` would have within the specified context.  You can write this, somewhat misleadingly, as:

```
(.) `inContext` \(.) -> (.) digitToInt
```

since `(.)` is as good an argument name for an anonymous lambda as `hole` is.  This is potentially confusing, since we're creating a local binding that shadows the top-level definition of `(.)`, but it's still naming the same thing (with a refined type), and this abuse of lambdas allowed us to write the original expression `(.) digitToInt` verbatim, with the appropriate boilerplate.

It's actually irrelevant how `inContext` is defined, if you're just asking GHCi for its type, so `inContext = undefined` would have worked.  But, just looking at the type signature, it's easy enough to give `inContext` a working definition:

```
inContext :: a -> (a -> b) -> a
inContext a _ = a
```

It turns out that this is just the definition of `const`, so `inContext = const` works, too.

You can use `inContext` to type multiple things at once, and they can be expressions instead of names.  To accommodate the former, you can use tuples; for the latter to work, you have use more sensible argument names in your lambas.

So, for example:

```
λ> :t (fromJust, fmap length) `inContext` \(a,b) -> a . b
(fromJust, fmap length) `inContext` \(a,b) -> a . b
  :: Foldable t => (Maybe Int -> Int, Maybe (t a) -> Maybe Int)
```

tells you that in the expression `fromJust . fmap length`, the types have been specialized to:

```
fromJust :: Maybe Int -> Int
fmap length :: Foldable t => Maybe (t a) -> Maybe Int
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do that using the `TypeApplications` extension, which allow you to explicitly specify which types you want to use to instantiate type parameters:

```
λ :set -XTypeApplications                                 
λ :t (.) @Char @Int
(.) @Char @Int :: (Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```

Note that the arguments must be in the exact order.

For functions that have a "regular" type signature like `foo :: a -> b`, the order is defined by the order in which the type parameters first appear in the signature.

For functions that use `ExplicitForall` like `foo :: forall b a. a -> b`, the order is defined by whatever it is in `forall`.

---

If you want to figure out the type specifically based on applying `(.)` to `digitToChar` (as opposed to just knowing which types to fill), I'm pretty sure you can't in GHCi, but I can highly recommend Haskell IDE support.

For example, here's how it looks for me in VSCode (here's [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell)):

[image]

Comment: Looks like it just replaces the placeholders with specific types. The question asks: is there a way to type something like `:t (.) Data.Char.digitToInt` instead of `:t (.) @Int @Char`?

Answer (score 5):

This is a minor variation on HTNW's answer.

Suppose we have any, potentially large, expression involving a polymorphic identifier `poly`

```
 .... poly ....
```

and we wonder how the polymorphic type was instantiated at that point.

This can be done exploiting two features of GHC: `asTypeOf` (as mentioned by HTNW) and [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typed-holes), as follows:

```
 .... (poly `asTypeOf` _) ....
```

Upon reading the `_` hole, GHC will generate an error reporting the type of the term that should be entered in place of that hole. Since we used `asTypeOf`, this must be the same as the type of the particular instance of `poly` we need in that context.

Here's an example in GHCi:

```
> ((.) `asTypeOf` _) Data.Char.digitToInt
<interactive>:11:17: error:
    * Found hole: _ :: (Char -> Int) -> (a -> Char) -> a -> Int
```